# Выполнение внешней команды exec

Tags: php, exec

Решил запустить парсер в несколько процессов. Для этого сначала запускаю программу в консоли так: "php parse.php m 4". После чего программа считает, по сколько товаров надо парсить и запускает 4 демона с параметрами offset и limit:

```
exec($path_php.' -q parse.php p '.$offset.' '.$limit.' '.$i.' > logs\daemon_'.$i.'.log 2>&1 &');
```

По документации, чтобы exec не зависал нужно, чтобы он ничего не выводил на экран, поэтому я сделал сохранение в лог, как вы видите. В программе у меня используется оператор print. Как сделать, чтобы exec не зависал? Вот запустились демоны и пускай работают в фоновом режиме себе.

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Вы написали `... > log 2>&1 &` и у вас php все равно ждет окончания выполнения? Или что? И `print` в демоне или в программе, запускающей демона?

Comment: print в демоне. Да, php ждёт окончания, более того в лог пишется только тогда, когда выполняется вся программа, а до этого никуда не пишется. Странно как-то. То есть у меня там циклом по штучно пишет в лог что спарсено, а он почему то ждёт пока весь цикл пройдёт и уже потом всю пачку записывает в лог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось всё дело в том, что я выполнял это в Windows. Перекинул скрипты на виртуалку на *nix системе, в моём случае Ubuntu - всё заработало как надо! Спасибо!)
А на windows у меня так и не удалось запускать в фоновом режиме, `start /B` не помогает :) Но ничего, виртуалка всегда под рукой)